# Apple's iOS ObjC compiler does not execute C++ parent's virtual destructor

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, destructor

We ran into this problem in the C++ side of the ObjC compiler:

```
class A {
   char *buf;
   public:
      A() { buf = new char[BUF_LENGTH]; }
      virtual ~A() { delete [] buf; }
};
class B: public A {
   public:
      virtual ~B() {}
};
```

For some reason A::~A() was not called from B::~B(), so the memory checker flagged B::~B() has a memory leak. When we eliminated the empty destructor, the code worked.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: The `~A` destructor was executed on my machine.  How are you compiling?  Do you have more code that demonstrates the misbehavior (the code as given doesn't run... there's no `main`).